# WPF Style for Interpreting ObservableCollection as Elements of StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, observablecollection, itemscontrol

I have an array (stored as an `ObservableCollection`) of data that I am dynamically instantiating, and I am linking it to an `ItemsControl` within a `StackPanel`. The data is formatted like so:

```
public class VariableValueList<T>
{
    public String Name {get; private set;}
    public IList<T> Values {get; private set;}
    ...
}
```

and my `ObservableCollection<VariableValueList<double>> IVCollection`, after constructed, is linked to `ItemsControl` with the following:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void Open_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    IndependentVariables.ItemsSource = IVCollection;
}
```

where `IndependentVariables` originates here:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
        <StackPanel>
            <ItemsControl Name="IndependentVariables" Style="{StaticResource IVCell}"></ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
```

I need to construct Style `IVCell` to have access to each `VariableValueList<double>` (once I get that, it will be trivial to obtain its `Name` and `Values` members).

I need the data to be formatted so that, for each element, `Name` and `Values` are printed, like so:

> Name
>
> Value Value Value ...
>
> Name
>
> Value Value Value ...
>
> ...

taking advantage of the existing `StackPanel`. I understand that there are at least two underlying questions in this problem.

1. How do I give a Style access to this array? (or: How do I modify a Style after I have the array?)
2. How do I instantiate new elements within a Style on the fly (e.g. for each array element)?

I really appreciate your help. If I'm trying to structure anything in this way *completely* wrong, please correct me. I am fairly new to WPF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need that extra `StackPanel`, because `ItemsControl` will create it's own panel for items.
Style doesn't need access to array, `ItemsControl` creates and manages containers for all items automatically. All you need is to provide `DataTemplate` for both types of items. You can use another `ItemsControl` inside `DataTemplate` for `VariableValueList<double>` to display items contained in `Values` property. To get horizontal layout, set custom `ItemsPanelTemplate` for that `ItemsControl`.

Simple style to start with:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}"
       x:Key="IVCell">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Values}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <WrapPanel />
                                <!-- or <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"> -->
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="2,0" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Should my members `Name` and `Values` be Dependency Properties in the code-behind? I'm not sure how to link them to `IVCollection`.

Comment: I should clarify. When attempting to bind in the XAML, `Name` and `Values` don't register as valid. If I add `DataType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}"` to `DataTemplate`, I can get the Dependency Properties, but I don't believe that's what I want in the long run.

Comment: In expression `TargetProperty={Binding SourceProperty}` - `TargetPropery` must be dependency property, but `SourceProperty` can be a simple property. If you really need these properties as targets for binding, then the answer is 'yes' - they must be dependency properties.

Comment: In general, you don't need to implement dependency properties for your object unless you are developing custom controls.

Comment: Okay. All I want to do is display (have access to) the data (the members of `IVCollection`) at this point. And that I don't have. So could my DataContext be off? It is `DataContext = this;` in my constructor.

Comment: As long as you assign `ItemsSource` manually, `DataContext` has no influence.